Why don't we see other countries testing missiles on a regular basis with public announcements?
As far as I see, among non-P5 countries the following countries regularly test missiles by publicly announcing them:

India
Iran
North Korea
Pakistan

Why don't we see other countries testing missiles on a regular basis with public announcements?
Don't they develop missiles? Are their missile developments less frequent? Don't they announce publicly? Or don't the corporate media show them very often?

You left out China from your short list. Whenever they 'test' around Taiwan they even officially call it punishment.

And South Korea's "response"  tests also come with official announcements https://www.nknews.org/2024/11/south-korea-tests-precision-strike-missile-in-response-to-north-korean-icbm/ E.g. "“Through this live-fire exercise, our military demonstrated both its firm resolve to respond decisively to any North Korean provocations and its capability to precisely strike the origin point of such provocations,” JCS said in Friday’s press release." It's just that the Western press covers them less.

And Turkey https://www.trtworld.com/turkiye/turkiyes-defence-giant-roketsan-successfully-tests-ballistic-missile-13345858 It's just that they'd don't manage to grab the headlines of the foreign press much. Despite the dramatic music in the video https://www.aa.com.tr/en/turkiye/turkish-defense-giant-successfully-tests-ballistic-missile-tayfun/2903920

Except maybe the Greek press https://www.ekathimerini.com/politics/foreign-policy/1238304/turkish-defense-firm-refers-to-blue-homeland-in-connection-with-drone-missile-test/

@264champagnebottlesonice, You left out China from your short list. Whenever they 'test' around Taiwan they even officially call it punishment. --- I left P5 out because, theoretically, they are permitted or have the power to do anything.

This reminds me of a mapporncirclejerk post.

Note that in the case of North Korea at least, in many cases they are not the ones announcing them, it's more often South Korea or Japan detecting and announcing (or rather denouncing) them.

What Dallman said, but also...
I think you are being overly broad in the term "missiles".
Many countries develop missiles like anti-ship missiles ASM, air-to-surface missiles, surface-to-air [SAM]....
For example German makes the Kormorant ASM, while Italy co-produces the Aster-30 SAM with France.
Those types of missiles don't "climb into space", are tested on weapons testing ranges and don't really need notices to be handed out to nervous neighbors.
A number of countries makes them, and many more countries buy them.  In that sense, to your question a) not that many countries develop them, while more use them.  You would still expect occasional test firings, but more to train the owners than to develop stuff.
What instead you are asking about are ICBM and IRBMs, as well as MRBMs.
Basically, those are all surface-to-surface ballistic (i.e. high-climbing) missiles with more than 1000 km range that are used to target large installations and/or cities.  And those have considerably more limited user bases:

The United States, Russia, China, France, India, the United Kingdom, Israel, and North Korea are the only countries known to have operational ICBMs. Pakistan is the only nuclear-armed state that does not possess ICBMs.

The IRBM list of operators is a bit wonky, but gives some idea:

IRBMs are currently[when?] operated by the People's Republic of China, India,3 Israel, and North Korea.5 The United States, USSR, Pakistan, United Kingdom, and France were former operators

And if you look at the MRBM page - which allows for more countries than the IRBM one, you will find China, France, India, Iran, Iraq (historical only), Israel, North Korea, Pakistan, Turkey, Russia listed.
So, basically, if you take the P5, add back Israel (which tends to be very hush-hush in this regard) and put in your list, those are pretty much the only countries that develop or use long range ground to ground missiles. With the addition of Turkey, which probably tested their new missile at some point.
In other words:

Don't they develop missiles? Are their missile developments less frequent?

"They" don't exist all that much, the club of countries fielding this weapon class, let alone developing them, is fairly limited.  Much of the long range strike conventional stuff, if deployed at all, is based on cruise missile technology.  To some extent, I suspect it's because that, without nuclear warheads or the capability for very high precision, that's a lot of $$$ to lob a warhead that will only have a limited effect.
For example, I believe Japan occasionally talks about long range strike capabilities, but so far it's not here yet and would be a antiship missile.
FWIW, maybe that list will climb up again.  I recently read an article somewhere claiming that cruise missiles are being considered  too vulnerable to defenses (probably as part of the Ukraine War lessons) and that ballistic missiles are a better bet to get things through.

What you missed (unless I glossed over it) is that announcing ballistic missile tests comes from the Cold War when the US and USSR agreed to announce tests so the other side wouldn't accidentally launch thermonuclear counterstrikes.

The first list may be small, but did any of United States, Russia, China, France or the United Kingdom made a test with a ICBM say since 2000?

Does it still count as a ballistic missile if it has a guidance system?

@quarague Yes, routinely.

@gerrit Thanks, I think that should go as a source into both this and John Dallmans answer.

Israel is not testing ICBM's per-se but they do test all kinds of "rocket propulsion systems" and satellite launchers. Since all launches must be done westward towards the Mediterranean sea they must be announced in advance to avoid accidents.

India and Pakistan have a long-running tense relationship, and likely view public missile tests as exerting political pressure on each other.
Iran and North Korea are enemies of the USA and likely view public missile tests as shows of strength.
Other countries develop missiles, but their tests don't get much publicity because they are simply tests, rather than political acts.

@JBH USA and Russia still do announcement at least to each other to prevent the apocalypse. Just papers usually don't make a sensation from it.

Meh, South Korea responds with "counter" tests with attached official declarations as to their intended meaning. https://www.nknews.org/2024/11/south-korea-tests-precision-strike-missile-in-response-to-north-korean-icbm/ They just don't get much Western press coverage. Perhaps in South Korea proper they get more.

@jbh not sure if sticking the sabre into someone chest counts a rattling. It doesn't even rattle.

Another potential reason is that tests by other countries don't have the potential to affect neighbours much if at all. E.g. the US typically tests over the continental USA or far away from any land in the middle of the ocean. Russia tends to test over Siberia or the North Pole region.

Do you have any source for the last sentence? It sounds plausible to me but as is this is a just a claim.

@quarague Usually Russian missiles use Kura as a target if you mean this. The trajectory there is good because you don't have to care about possible debris fallen to other countries.

@quarague well, for example, Israel has a fairly active IRBM programme, and run tests extensively. These do show up in English-language media, but rarely warrant more than just a short mention (I'd bet Arabic and Persian-language media cover those much more extensively, though).


The test of a missile can have different purposes, among them R&D, training, or propaganda.
The public announcement of a missile test can have different purposes, safety or propaganda.
The test of a missile may violate UNSC resolutions.

News media tend to get attentive when a missile test either reveals a new capability, or violates UNSC resolutions, or comes with a lot of propaganda. Or when it fails, like the recent Russian test. Successful tests by established missile powers do not grab the headlines.

I upvoted but "violates UNSC resolutions" has also become routine from that guy.

A final category is when the opponents of a certain country raise it with the press https://www.reuters.com/world/asia-pacific/taiwan-alert-over-multiple-waves-missile-firing-inland-china-2024-09-29/ I suppose this is rouhgly covered by "comes with a lot of propaganda".
